# How to check a css file is minified or not using php

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, minify

I am creating an SEO analyzer that will check whether a CSS and js file is minified or not. An HTML parser will extract URL's of CSS and js files from a website.

How can I check whether that CSS/js file is minified or not using PHP?

CSS file's URL can be like this:

```
http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:200,300,400,500,600,700,800
http://www.inforge.in/css/style.css
```

Comment: What is your definition of "minified"?  When analyzing the file, what would you consider a criteria for minified vs. not minified?  Since there's no formal definition, this can only be done by deciding what your criteria is and then examining the file to see if it meets that criteria or not.

Comment: Just a quick idea .
I would check if the file has only one line , and whether unnecessary spaces would be removed . In addition, I would check the presence of comments.

Comment: Just check if the file has `\n` in it. If it does not have any, then usually it is minified

Comment: Or check if the ratio of newline characters to total file size is above some threshold? A minified file may still have several newlines if there is a copyright notice or other comment at the top, and if several libraries have been bundled into a single file they may each have their own heading comment on a new line even if the file is minified.

Comment: i just want to check whether there are new lines and spaces. That's all

Comment: OK, so what then are you actually asking?

Comment: ok. I write the code for that. But as @nnnnnn mentioned, even minified css and js files have spaces and new lines.

Comment: just one more approach you  can try.. record the original file size of the css, minimize the file yourself , compare both and figure out if it was compressed or not

Comment: There is no standard for minified code.  The only true test is to (1) forcibly minify a copy of the file and compare it to the source, or (2) set up your own minification standard and check each condition against the CSS file.  If your site is hurting for performance, then you would probably not want to do that in realtime.  If you are trying to perform maintenance scripts, then why not create your own manager/logger and minify all CSS on the first pass?  If you're creating your own SEO analyzer, I guess the advice is don't.  There's probably already one out there that considered everything.

Answer (score 2):

This is a PHP function that can parse through a website and find how many local CSS files aren't minified. It's a bit more than you asked for but should help you out.

```
<?php

/**
 * Find the number of unminified CSS files on a website
 * @param  string  $url            The root URL of the website to test
 * @param  integer $lines_per_file What's the max number of lines a minified CSS file should have?
 * @return integer                 Number of CSS files on a website that aren't minified
 */
function how_many_unminified_css_files( $url, $lines_per_file = 3 )
    $unminimized_css_files = 0;

    // Get the website's HTML
    $html = file_get_contents( $url );

    // Find all local css files
    preg_match( "/({$url}.*\.css)/gi", $html, $css_files );

    // Remove the global match that preg_match returns
    array_shift( $css_files );

    // Loop through all the local CSS files
    // And count how many lines they have
    foreach( $css_files as $css_file ) {
        $linecount = 0;

        // "Open" the CSS file
        $handle = fopen($css_file, "r");

        // Count the number of lines
        while(!feof($handle)){
          $line = fgets($handle);
          $linecount++;
        }

        // Close the CSS file
        fclose($handle);

        // If the CSS file has more lines than we deem appropriate, 
        // we'll consider it not minified
        if ( $linecount > $lines_per_file ) {
            $unminimized_css_files++;
        }
    }

    // Return the number of files that we don't think are minified
    return $unminimized_css_files;
}
```

Comment: How do you decide the `lines_per_file` value?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function is_mini($fileName){
  $f = @fopen($fileName, 'r'); $l = strlen(file_get_contents($fileName));
  if(strlen(fgets($f, $l)) === $l){
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

It opens a file based on `$fileName` for reading, hence the `'r'`, then tests for the `strlen()` of the file against a single line returned by `fgets()`. So it really just makes sure it's one line of code.

Comment: can you tell me the logic behind it?